# Code will build on Xcode but no run on Playground. Why?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground

So, I'm a beginner with Swift and please forgive me if this is some stupid thing I'm missing.

I'm trying to test some JSON requests and I got the SwiftyJSON lib. It will build within Xcode, but I would like to use Playground so I'd be able to easily run some tests with it. Thing is, I pasted the entire code of the lib on Playground and and it doesn't work. There are all sorts of compilation errors on Playground that didn't show on Xcode.

What is different? What are the limitations within Playground that could be causing this?

Comment: What's a sample error?

Comment: It's impossible to know what could be going wrong without more context.  Please post the full code you're trying.

Comment: Remember that playgrounds are sandboxed and have no access to your hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the SwiftyJSON.swift file in Sources folder in your playground & build .Thats it you can use SwifyJSON[image]